# How to assign string to enum using C++98?

Tags: string, enums, c++98

I have declared an enum and a string

`string SS;`

`enum CS {AA, BB, CC, DD};`

and I want to create a variable named CN of type CS and assign the SS to enum CS.

I looked it up in the internet, most solutions are for C++11 and above.
I tried to use map, but it would not work.

```
map<string, enum> CN;
  CN["AA"]=0;
  CN["BB"]=1;
  CN["CC"]=2;
  CN["DD"]=3;
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?
How do I create CS as a type enum CS?
I will really appreciate it!

Comment: `enum CS {"AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"};` isn't valid C++ Did you mean `enum CS {AA, BB, CC, DD};`?

Comment: yes, thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of map is nearly right, so long as the values are initialised in function scope.

I.e. this is OK

```
std::map<std::string, CS> CN;

int main() {
    CN["AA"]=AA;
    CN["BB"]=BB;
    CN["CC"]=CC;
    CN["DD"]=DD;

    // use CN
}
```

However this isn't

```
std::map<std::string, CS> CN;
CN["AA"]=AA; // can't have expressions at namespace scope
CN["BB"]=BB;
CN["CC"]=CC;
CN["DD"]=DD;

int main() {
    // try to use CN
}
```